Assessing sex differences: sex first as response, then as covariate in regression
I have a large number of mutually correlated measurements of each person in a cohort (in matrix X) and also some background data (person's height, weight etc) which I want to take into account (in matrix Z). I want to know if there exists any linear combination of variables in X which would differ among men and women (while Z is taken into account).
Would it be ok to proceed as follows:
(1) Using sex as bivariate response and (Z,X) as covariates, apply Lasso logistic regression (using BIC criterion to identify optimal level of regularization) to find the best linear combination of the variables in X for the purpose on predicting sex. 
(2) Use the linear combination found in (1) as the response and sex and matrix Z as covariates in a linear regression model. Find the p-value for sex in this model.
(3) If p<p(crit)*, there exists a linear combination of the X-variables that differs by sex, otherwise the measurements in X or any linear combination of them does not differ by sex (while Z is taken into account).
*The reference value p_crit used above is obtained by repeating the above procedure (1)-(2) for 1000 simulated data sets, where X is replaced by random normal variates which are independent of sex, then listing the 1000 corresponding p-values and obtaining p_crit as the 0.05 quantile of these simulated p-values.
My idea is to find a linear combination of the X-variables that involves only a few variables, and therefore I would prefer the Lasso regression.
